# CSOM Folder.listItemAllFields won't load the item (Sharepoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, csom, folder

I have been trying to load the item version of a folder via csom for some time now, but no matter how hard I try, it just won't load.

For example : here's one of the configuration I have tried

```
        string UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
        string clearPwd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];

        SecureString pwd = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in clearPwd.ToCharArray()) pwd.AppendChar(c);
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url);
        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, pwd);

        //Getting folders
        Web web = context.Web;
        context.Load(web);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        context.Load(web.Lists);
        context.ExecuteQuery();            

        Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Office%20Lu");
        context.Load(folder);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        ListItem item = folder.ListItemAllFields;
        context.Load(item);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        context.Load(item.RoleAssignments);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
```

The application crashes on the last line with a "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException" error

```
context.Load(item.RoleAssignments);
```

[image]

No matter what I do, whenever I try to get a List Item from a folder, the program just won't load it. Even if I remove the load on item.roleAssignments, my "item" variable looks as though I never loaded it : it doesn't have an Id, any fieldProperties, etc ...

I tried many configuration and the only thing that works is to get the corresponding list for every folder then do a list.GetItemByUniqueId(folder.UniqueId). The problem is that I have a lot of folder to treat and it slows down the application a lot.

I'm fairly certain that I did something similar in another project and it was working. I cannot figure out what's wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

For information i'm using Microsoft.SharepointOnline.CSOM version 16.1.21909.12000

Answer (score 0):

The code is working for me. Are you sure you've used the correct server relative URL for the folder in your code?

In my test code it was formatted like this

```
/sites/Demo4/Lists/Folder Test/Folder 2
```

Also, if you want to reference the root folder of the list or library, use the `RootFolder` property of the `List` object rather than the `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` method of the `Web` object.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why it's not working. I swear I have been doing this before ... 

The folder has properties such as name and relativeurl so I think i'm using the right link. I'm on an ASP.NET page using MVC so maybe it has limited options ? Or maybe it comes from visual studio 2022... I'll keep trying and post the solution here if I find it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you load a root folder which does not have ListItemAllFields or RoleAssigments at all. The root folder is the same as the library or list. So you have to get these properties from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Might be folder not identified, for me folder with "-" is giving 401 error